# Are there integral domains unknown to be UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Are there integral domains unknown to be UFD ??

Im not asking about an infinite set of rings , but a specific integral domain unknown to be a UFD.

What are the simplest examples ?

Are there patterns in the norms of these problematic integral domains ?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one

Comment: It's not known whether ${\cal{O}}_K$ is a UFD for $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ with $d > 0$ arbitrary. Take your pick. (There are quite a few integral domains, and "most" of them aren't UFDs.)

Comment: @anomaly Given any specific $d$, we can surely calculate whether it's a UFD, at least if $d$ is small enough for computational techniques to be effective. The point is that it is open whether there are infinitely many such $d$.

Comment: What does the word "norm" mean in the last question? A general integral domain does not have a "norm" function, problematic or not.

Comment: What integraal domain does not have a norm ???

Comment: You did not answer my question: what is a norm on an integral domain? There are norms on (some) vector spaces, norm maps on finite extensions of fields, and on Euclidean domains the size function is sometimes called a norm. These are all completely different uses of the word "norm". For an arbitrary integral domain I have never heard of a norm function on it in some fourth sense of the word. Your response to being asked what you mean by that term, with three question marks no less, is not helpful. Please enlighten us by giving a definition of a norm on a *general* integral domain.

Comment: Hmm not sure if this helps but the norm is the determinant of the representation matrix. For instance norm $Z(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3, \sqrt 6) $ is equal to $a^2 + 2 b^2 + 3 c^2 + 6 d^2$.

Comment: That's like the field norm on a finite extension. Almost no integral domain has a finite basis over $\mathbf Z$ or $\mathbf Q$. Please give some thought to an actual general definition of whatever you think a "norm" is supposed to be and then see what it is for the ring $\mathbf Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ of polynomials over $\mathbf Z$ in countably many variables, for the field $\mathbf R$, and for the field $\mathbf F_p(x)$ of rational functions in one variable over the field of prime order $p$. Then you will understand my surprise that you asked how an integral domain "does not have a norm???".

Comment: Yeah im talking about finite extensions. Srr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is conjectured that the maximal real subfield of the cyclotomic field $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{2^n})$ has class number one, or equivalently is a UFD, for all $n$ but this is only proved for $n\leq 7$. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82480/non-trivial-class-number-at-some-finite-level-in-the-cyclotomic-mathbfz-p-e. So taking $n=8$ gives a specific example for the OP's first question at the time this is being written. It is a number field of degree $2^{8-1} = 128$ over $\mathbf Q$. In the future if the case $n=8$ gets settled then change $n$ to $9$. If the conjecture is settled (affirmatively) for all $n$ then I will happily sacrifice the correctness of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

For a Dedekind domain, UFD is equivalent to PID. Hence , for the ring of integers $A_k$ of a number field $k$, UFD is equivalent to "  class number 1 ". Among all imaginary quadratic fields $k= \mathbf Q(\sqrt d)$ the only $A_k$ which are PID correspond to $d=-1, -2, -, -7, -11, -19, -43, -67, -163$ (conjecture of Gauss, theorem of Heegner-Stark). The analogous problem for real quadratic fields is open : it is known for example that $A_k$ is a PID for $d=2, 3, 5, 6,7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 29, 33, 37, 41, 57, 73$, but could there be an infinite number of such PID's ?

Among the cyclotomic fields $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$ , the only $A_k$ which are PID correspond to $n$=1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, 32, 33, 35, 36, 40, 44, 45, 48, 60, 84, as well as the values  $2n$ of the odd $n$'s in this list (because $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)=\mathbf Q(\zeta_{2n})$) .