# For which value of $n$ the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ is a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> For which value of $n$ the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ is a UFD ?

I am literally very confused about it. I know that when $n=2,3,-1,-2$ (there are many other value also) then the ring is UFD but I want to know some generalized principles that help in decision making. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example where it is not ufd?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-n-ge-3-not-a-ufd?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726826/when-is-mathbbz-sqrtd-not-an-ufd-for-d1

Comment: I'm not sure that the general case is known (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1901967)).

Comment: Can you see what went wrong in that case?

Answer (score 2):

First, if $n\equiv 1\mod4$, it can't be a U.F.D., because it is *not* the integral closure of $\mathbf Z$ in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt n)$, and a U.F.D. is integrally closed.
 Second, when it is the integral closure, it is equivalent to say it is a P.I.D.

*Starck-Heegner's theorem*  gives the $9$ values of $n<0$ for which the ring of integers is principal, which are all congruent to $1$, except $-1$ and $-2$.

For a positive $n$, one doesn't even know if there is an infinite number of them (*Gauß' conjecture). In each case one may study the group of *ideal classes*, which is trivial if and only if the ring is principal. One way of showing it is not is to find two different decompositions of an element as a product of irreducible elements.